# TIMEOUT not working django-redis-cache

Tags: python, django, caching, redis

I have the settings cache and my TIMEOUT not working. My cache never do update.

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'redis_cache.cache.RedisCache',
        'LOCATION': 'localhost:6379',
        'TIMEOUT': 5,
        'OPTIONS': {
            "SOCKET_CONNECT_TIMEOUT": 5,  # in seconds
            "SOCKET_TIMEOUT": 5,  # in seconds
            'DB': 1,
            'PASSWORD': '',
            'PARSER_CLASS': 'redis.connection.HiredisParser',
            'PICKLE_VERSION': 2,
        },
    },
}
```

Comment: if you are expiring items in the cache after 5 seconds, that means you shouldn't be caching anything at all

Comment: but this is problem, I set 5 seconds for test, but not import the time, he don't cache anything.

Comment: one place your say " My cache never do update." and then you say "he don't cache anything" which one is it?

Comment: The problem and the following, my cache stored the information, days later I made some insertions and deletes in the database, but it did not catch those changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

everyone my problem has been solved with django-rest-framework-cache. It seems that django-redis-cache is having trouble understanding the timeout.

https://github.com/Onyo/django-rest-framework-cache/blob/master/README.md

Comment: I used that and it helped me a lot. Thank you very much.